# Retain selectedvalue of dropdownlist after postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, postback, code-behind

I've found this question asked countless times, but the answers haven't worked for me:

I have an `asp:Dropdownlist` that is dynamically bound from an `asp:Objectdatasource`. A button calls a codebehind function to store the selected value. However, in the click event function the value of the dropdown is always reset to default, AFAIK due to a postback that is called before the click event handler. When debugging I've checked that `ViewStateMode` is enabled and `EnableViewState` is true. I've been stuck with this for hours now, does anyone have a clue?

ASPX markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" DataSourceID="AvailableNivamalerODS" ID="AddNivamalerDDL" />
<asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="AvailableNivamalerODS" TypeName="Nivamaler.NivamalerPresenter"
        SelectMethod="GetAvailableNivamalers"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
<asp:Button runat="server" 
    Text="Legg til" 
    OnClick="AddNivamalerToTjstpl" 
    ID="AddNivamalerBtn"
    UseSubmitBehavior="False"
    CssClass="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"/>
```

Codebehind

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        AddNivamalerDDL.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Click event handler:

```
Protected Sub AddNivamalerToTjstpl(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddNivamalerBtn.Click
    Dim nivamalerId As Integer = AddNivamalerDDL.SelectedValue
    'Here nivamalerId is always the default value
End Sub
```

Cheers!

**EDIT**

The replies to previous question have basically said to put the data binding in the `Page_Init` method or the `Page_Load` method after `!IsPostBack`, which didn't help me.

Also a disclaimer: This is a legacy project with tons more code (the relevant code is new), but I tried to snip out the relevant bits. As far as I can see the rest of the code shouldn't affect this, but I can't be certain as I am still fairly new to ASP.Net

Comment: If you have seen this question asked countless times and the answers haven't worked for you, you should describe those failed answers in your question. Otherwise you are likely to get many of those same answers again which will be a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: Good point. They usually say that you have to do the databinding either in page_init og after checking !IsPostBack in Page_Load, but I'm already doing that. As a sidenote I've noticed that even if I don't expicitly call DataBind() on the dropdown, it will bind correctly. Also, I found one solution suggesting that you can put the value in the Session and select it after the postback, but it feels like bad practice to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, and as has been pointed out, the posted code is incomplete: The dropdown is inside a JQuery-ui dialog, which makes the dropdown lose its state. I ended up with a workaround with a Javascript function which copied the selected value to a hidden field outside the dialog and using the hidden field value in the codebehind

Answer (score 0):

Put your page_load code into the page_Init section. The asp lifecycle will make the dropdown list databind() be absolutely meaningless if it is in the page load section here because a Postback causes the whole page to resubmit itself to the point of page_load and since you have the if not ispostback statement, it will reload the page structure but won't run your page load code and that is where you are losing your value. Other than that the code is fine.

Comment: This does not solve my problem. The SelectedValue of the dropdownlist is  still reset to the default value in the click event handler

Comment: if you move it to the Init section then don't use the if not ispostback statement to do your databinding because there is no point. If that doesn't work then something else within your program is causing this problem that you haven't mentioned in this post. If the dropdown list binds without calling databind() then why exactly are you still trying to use it in the code behind? and where do you even assign the datatextfield or datavaluefield properties of your dropdownlist? bc if you don't assign anything then of course the return will be default value.

Comment: @grankdubya13 You were right, the code with the problem wasn't posted. Turns out JQuery-UI dialogs don't play well with ViewStates. I also removed the explicit databind. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, I don't know if this would help, but check out putting it inside an <asp:UpdatePanel> I had a recent issue with maintaining values and trying to use buttons that had to have autopostback to run their functions, but i didn't want my page to reload until i got ready to actually hit a submit button. I put all of my page inside that bad boy except for my submit button and it worked like a charm. It kept the page from refreshing itself every time i called a function for a button and therefore helped to maintain my viewstate.

Comment: I tried putting it in an UpdatePanel, which had no effect by itself, and when I added autopostback the selected value would reset when then panel refreshed, ie a second after a value is chosen